# How to log -lightly- compilation commands on Linux (with GCC)?

Tags: linux, logs, gcc

#### There are cases where logging the compilation commands by GCC on Linux makes sense

(I want to log the compilation command, its success or failure, the CPU and real time spent to run it, the size of source files ...). The [Ctuning](https://ctuning.org/) project or [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) is an (advanced) example motivating this. A simpler motivation is to make simple statistics on past compilations (e.g. find the ones that ate a source file bigger than 100k, or took more than 5 seconds, e.g. to decide refactoring a big C++ source file into a few smaller ones.).

#### I didn't found any simple program doing so (on Linux)... If you know one (open source), please tell.

However, there could be simpler uses of these. I just coded on my [github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/) repository a C++ program [logged-gcc.cc](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/logged-gcc.cc) (GPLv3+ licensed) and its build script [compile-logged-gcc.sh](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/compile-logged-gcc.sh)

Typical use might be to have `$HOME/bin/` *early* in your  `$PATH` and to add the compiled `logged-gcc` executable and `logged-g++` symlink (in the same `$HOME/bin/`  directory) then to have there shell scripts like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file  ~/bin/gcc which should be executable
export LOGGED_CFLAGS='-g -Wall'
export LOGGED_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc-10
exec $HOME/bin/logged-gcc "$@"
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
# file  ~/bin/g+ which should be executable
export LOGGED_CXXFLAGS='-g -Wall'
export LOGGED_GXX=/usr/bin/g++-10
exec $HOME/bin/logged-g++ "$@"
```

Of course, run

```
$HOME/bin/logged-gcc --help
```

to get help, and

```
$HOME/bin/logged-gcc --version
```

to get version information.

(Actually, clever `$PATH` tricks with symlinks could avoid the above shell scripts)

Then use (on Debian) `cat /var/log/messages` to see the logging.

---

The point is of course not to just redirect a `gcc` or `g++` command, but to also measure the CPU and elapsed time it did take and the size of input source files to `gcc`.  This is what I mean by "logging compilation commands" - being able to do some statistics on them later.

I am aware of the `-time` [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) (or `-freport-time`) to `gcc`. It does not measure size of input source files. I am also aware of [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) machinery (see [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report and the old [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project).

**I want to log -and somehow benchmark- compilation commands as transparently as possible** (e.g. with just a `$PATH` trick like above, and later by simply setting environment variables such as `LOGGER_SQLITE` in my `~/.zshrc`), **and with *minor* overhead** (so forking a few more processes such as [logger(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) or [du(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) is *not* an option, since some compilations (e.g. of a small C source code, see my [misc-basile](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile) repository for examples) can last less than a tenth of a second, see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)). Writing a benchmarking [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) may depend on the version of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), is probably too heavy and could require e.g. changes in `Makefile`-s to [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) that plugin on every `gcc` command.

A concrete use case could be the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project in a few months (start of 2021). Since it is generating more and more of its C++ code, and compilation timing should drive the decision to generate fewer but larger C++ files, or more but smaller ones, especially when using several standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or GUI toolkits such as [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) in the generated C++ code.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clear enough!

Comment: Ehm... you know how to capture and redirect output in shell generally? It needs no command, it's in-built in every shell: `command > logfile.log 2>&1`. As such your question seems more promotion of your programme - which seems to solve a non-existing problem; and the question seems more on-topic in StackOverflow or Superuser.

Comment: So please refer to me to some script or program collecting compilation information.

Comment: `time your_command` and `du -h --max-depth 1 your_path` are your friend

Comment: Btw, what I would do: if it is a script, then I would pipe the output to a [logger](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command. In the more likely case that it runs from a system service, then I would use an appropriate systemd service file for the task ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file)) with a correctly configured [syslog-ng](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslog-ng). On some mysterious reason, syslog-ng is disfavorized in this decade by the major linux distros, so also other logging daemon is okay.